# How can I modify a inner text of child in a xml file?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

How can I modify an inner text of the child in an XML file?
Can someone give me an example via code snippet?
I am using Python.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dictionary>
    <!--GUI-Parameter-->
    <item>
        <key typ="str">WindowTop</key>
        <value typ="int">20</value><!--[Pix]-->
    </item>
    <item>
        <key typ="str">WindowLeft</key>
        <value typ="int">20</value><!--[Pix]-->
    </item>
```

Here I want to modify the value of the key WindowTop from 20 to 40.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the element using `xpath` then you can change the value using `text` property

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

elmt = root.find('.//item[key="WindowTop"]/value')
if elmt is not None:
    elmt.text = str(40)

tree.write('output.xml')
```

**Output:**

```
<dictionary>
    
    <item>
        <key typ="str">WindowTop</key>
        <value typ="int">40</value>
        
    </item>
    <item>
        <key typ="str">WindowLeft</key>
        <value typ="int">20</value>
        
    </item>
</dictionary>
```